# Custom css is not working in kendo ui in angular 5

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui

I have included a grid from kendo UI on my page.

Now as I want to change the background color of the rows in the grid, I used the rowClass function that is given in the [documentation][1] of kendo UI.

The documentation showed how to use this rowclass function and add a class to the row and as the CSS is written in the class that is defined the CSS changes will be applied to the row of a grid, but when I try, the class which I want to add to the rows of the grid is added successfully which I found by inspecting the element and checked the class name in the browser developer tools, but the CSS changes which are written inside the class which is added to the grid rows are not getting applied at all

How can this be possible class has been added but the CSS inside the class isn't working.

Please check plnkr.co/edit/kQxjG7acT6z5bVLYeC3d?p=preview

Comment: Please check the plunker where I reproduced this problem 

    https://plnkr.co/edit/kQxjG7acT6z5bVLYeC3d?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

In your component you wrote `stylesUrls` instead of `styleUrls` http://plnkr.co/edit/dkojl4WnkjXGQY7e5TwI?p=preview

Comment: Didn't notice he called css file this way. I usually use such names for global styles)

Comment: let me check and let you know

Comment: It is the styleUrls* that is added automatically when the component is generated, what is the difference between styleUrls and stylesUrls

Comment: By the way by stylesUrls worked for me, thank you so much

Comment: When I changed the styleUrls to stylesUrls, I'm getting an error message saying stylesUrls does not exist in type Component

Comment: I think stylesUrls doesn't exist, the doc about styles is pretty detailed https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-files-in-component-metadata

Comment: So you are saying me to use styles and include the css file in it instead of styleUrls?

Comment: no I'm saying stylesUrls with a 's' at styles doesn't exist but styleUrls (without s at style) exist, the docs about component styles is good.  Don't include the css in it because you would loose the component scoped styles...

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been solved, it is because I didn't insert ViewEncapsulation.None in my component